# exam class: hide points but still be in grade table

Tags: exam

I am using the exam class to write my exercise sheets. 
Now I want to have something like

**Exercise 1 (5+5 points)**

(a) lala

(b) lulu

but I still want to use \gradetable.

My Question would be if you can fill the grade table manual or hide points of \question because having it like above issues errors.

Add: I've tried

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{exam}                                                   
\noprintanswers 
\addpoints
\nopointsinmargin    

\begin{document}\parindent=0pt


\begin{center} %copied from handbook
\hqword{Aufgabe Nr.:}
\hpword{Punktzahl:}
\htword{\textbf{Summe}}
\hsword{Davon erreicht:}
\cellwidth{2.2em}
\settabletotalpoints{2334}
\gradetable[h][questions]
\end{center}


\begin{questions}
\uplevel{ \textbf{Exercise 1: (5+5 Points)}}
\question[3]\begin{enumerate}
\item lala
\item lulu
\end{enumerate}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

But instead of having 3 in the table I want to get 10 (=5+5).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Try `\pointsinmargin   \pointformat{} `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be like this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{exam}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\noprintanswers
\addpoints
\nopointsinmargin   %<---------------
%\pointformat{}    %<---------------
\qformat{\textbf{Exercise \thequestion:\quad (\thepoints)}\hfill}
\begin{document}\parindent=0pt


\begin{center} %copied from handbook
\hqword{Aufgabe Nr.:}
\hpword{Punktzahl:}
\htword{\textbf{Summe}}
\hsword{Davon erreicht:}
\cellwidth{2.2em}
\settabletotalpoints{2334}
\gradetable[h][questions]
\end{center}


\begin{questions}
%\uplevel{ \textbf{Exercise 1: (5+5 Points)}}
\question[10]
\begin{parts}
\part lala
\part lulu
\end{parts}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

or like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{exam}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\noprintanswers
\addpoints
\nopointsinmargin   %<---------------
\pointformat{}    %<---------------
\qformat{}
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
\setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
}
\begin{document}\parindent=0pt


\begin{center} %copied from handbook
\hqword{Aufgabe Nr.:}
\hpword{Punktzahl:}
\htword{\textbf{Summe}}
\hsword{Davon erreicht:}
\cellwidth{2.2em}
\settabletotalpoints{2334}
\gradetable[h][questions]
\end{center}


\begin{questions}
\uplevel{\textbf{Exercise 1: (5+5 Points)}}
\question[10]
\begin{parts}
\vspace{-1.5\baselineskip}
\part lala
\part lulu
\end{parts}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But I still don't get your claim

> because having it like above issues errors